# client creates new socket object everytime the server is on

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

i've done a socket programming with client residing on android and server residing on the desktop ....... whenever server is down as we know client lost the connection.....so it undergoes a looping until it connects to server.......

here the problem is in the below code

```
tabletclient = new Socket(SERVER_IP, TAB_SERVER_PORT);
```

in the while loop in the case of lost connection.........but when the connection is on it again creates a new object........

can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem..........

**In the client side**

```
while(true){
        try {

            tabletclient = new Socket(SERVER_IP, TAB_SERVER_PORT);

            tabletout = new PrintWriter(tabletclient.getOutputStream());
            in = new Scanner(tabletclient.getInputStream());
            try
            {
                if((line = in.nextLine())!=null)
                {
                    // my task to be done 
                }
            }catch(Exception d){
                System.out.println("Connection from server has lost.........tabletclient.isConnected()----->"+tabletclient.isConnected());

            }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {  System.out.println("Entered 2.........");
            } catch (IOException e) {  System.out.println("Entered 3.........");e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
```

**In in the Server side**

```
:
:
       private Set <Socket> TABhs=new HashSet<Socket>();
:
:
        new Thread(new TABServerThread()).start(); // runs in background
:
:
:
 class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        private ServerSocket server;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
                System.out.println("Server Start the server at port " + SERVER_PORT
                        + " and waiting for clients...");
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    System.out.println("Server Accept socket connection: "
                                    + socket.getLocalAddress());
                      new Thread(new ClientHandler(socket)).start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

private static PrintWriter out;

    class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private Scanner in;

        public ClientHandler(Socket clietSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clietSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                in = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                String line;
                System.out.println("ClientHandlerThread Start communication with : "+ clientSocket.getLocalAddress());
                try{
                while((line = in.nextLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("ClientHandlerThread Client says: " + line);
                    String dat[]=line.split("#");
                        String query="insert into table_orders (tableno,kotno, orders,status) values('"+dat[1]+"','"+dat[0]+"','"+dat[2]+"','pending')";
                        try {
                            int i= dbGetDet.insertDetails(query);
                            if(i>0)
                            {
                             fillTable();
                             filtercomboBox();
                             out.print("success");
                             out.flush();
                             for(Socket so:TABhs)
                             {
                                PrintWriter ot = new PrintWriter(so.getOutputStream());
                                ot.println("tableallocation#"+dat[1]);
                                ot.flush();
                             }
                                System.out.println("SENDED 'SUCCESS' TO CLIENT");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(MYClientclass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } 
                   // }
                }
                }catch(Exception r){}
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

**In the Button click of server**

```
String stat=status_combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String tables=tableno_combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String kotno=kotno_combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
  if(stat.equals("Processing"))
  {
        try {
            TABhs = new CopyOnWriteArraySet(TABhs);
            int soint=1;
            System.out.println("TABhs Processing--------------------->"+TABhs.size());
            for(Iterator <Socket> it=TABhs.iterator();it.hasNext();)
            { 
                Socket so=it.next();
                System.out.println("SEEE SOCKET Processing"+soint+"----->"+so.isClosed());
                PrintWriter ot = new PrintWriter(so.getOutputStream());
                ot.println("tableupdate#"+tables+"#"+kotno+"#processing");
                ot.flush();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "<html><body>Table Kot Status Changed to <b>Processing</b></body></html>");
                soint++;
            }

            System.out.println("TABhs Processing--------------------->"+TABhs.size());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MYClientclass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
```

**NOW EACH TIME WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED THE OUTPUT IS AS GIVEN BELOW**

**FISRT CLICK**

```
SEEE SOCKET Ready 1----->false
Server Accept socket connection: /192.168.1.74
SEEE SOCKET Ready 2----->false
TABhs--------------------->2
```

**SECOND CLICK**

```
SEEE SOCKET Ready 1----->false
SEEE SOCKET Ready 2----->false
Server Accept socket connection: /192.168.1.74
SEEE SOCKET Ready 3----->false
TABhs--------------------->4
```

**FOURTH CLICK**

```
SEEE SOCKET Ready 1----->false
SEEE SOCKET Ready 2----->false
SEEE SOCKET Ready 3----->false
Server Accept socket connection: /192.168.1.74
SEEE SOCKET Ready 4----->false
TABhs--------------------->5
```

Comment: Solve what problem? You aren't closing the socket, but you haven't actually said what your problem is.

Comment: SIR CAN YOU SEE THE OUTPUT (UPDATED) THIS IS THE PROBLEM I'M FACING............EACH TIME THE HASHSET IS INCREASING

Comment: DON'T SHOUT AT PEOPLE IN CAPITALS. IT IS CONSIDERED EXTREMELY OFFENSIVE.

Comment: i'm really sorry sir.........

Comment: You still haven't explained your problem clearly. We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at the client's side you read a line and then create a new connection. 
I think you must keep reading the socket until it's closed or an error occurs.

For example:

```
while (true)
{
    tabletclient = null;
    int loop = 0;
    // loop until a connection is established
    while (tabletclient == null)
    {
        try
        {
            tabletclient = new Socket(SERVER_IP, TAB_SERVER_PORT);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // set the value to quit when no connection could be established
            if (loop++ > 100)
                return;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        tabletout = new PrintWriter(tabletclient.getOutputStream());
        in = new Scanner(tabletclient.getInputStream());
        // read the socket until it's closed or an error occurs
        try
        {
            while ((line = in.nextLine()) != null)
            {
                // my task to be done
            }

        }
        catch (Exception d)
        {
            System.out.println("Connection from server has lost.........tabletclient.isConnected()----->"
                            + tabletclient.isConnected());
        }
        tabletsocket.close();
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Entered 2.........");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Entered 3.........");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, you must close the server side when the transfer from the server to the client is completed.